# Dinamically load usercontrols and setting property in its viewmodel (Prism WPF)

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I have a working Prism WPF application whose main target is UI for factory operators and communication with factory machines.

Main UI view (`MachineDashboard`) is bound to its viewmodel (`MachineDashboardViewModel`), where based on the property `MachineId` all communications with Machines and BL is done.

This property is now initialized from application settings.

Now I need to upgrade application, so it will show UI for different machines (up to 4).
Basically, I need to show up to 4 different views (MachineDashboards).

I added dependency property to UserControl `MachineDashboard` `MachineId_DP`, through which I’m setting property `MachineId` in ViewModel `MachineDashboardViewModel`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style  TargetType="local:MachineDashboard">
            <Setter Property="MachineId_DP" Value="{Binding MachineId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

If I want to show UserCotrols for different Machines in HomeView, I can now add usercontrols and define machine's Ids

```
<WrapPanel Grid.Row="0">
    <local:MachineDashboard MachineId_DP="1"  Margin="10"/>
    <local:MachineDashboard MachineId_DP="2"  Margin="10"/>
    <local:MachineDashboard MachineId_DP="3"  Margin="10"/>
    <local:MachineDashboard MachineId_DP="4"  Margin="10"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

which works exactly as I want.

But if I try to do the same thing via ItemsControl (since exact list of machines is loaded from database), binding of the `MachineId` is not working. Correct number of Usercontrols are loaded, but `MachineIds` are not passed down to `MachineDashboardViewModel`

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Machines}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
                <local:MachineDashboard  MachineId_DP="{Binding MachineId}"  Margin="10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In fact, even if I try to add datatemplate with fixed MachineId_DP parameter, the result is the same.

```
<DataTemplate >
    <local:MachineDashboard  MachineId_DP="3"  Margin="10"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have checked every stackoverflow’s entry with similar question without appropriate answer, usually the debate was around the fact why having viewmodel for usercontrol.
This usercontrol (MachineDashoard) is in fact set of around 50 controls like labels, datagrids, buttons, etc with links to other entry dialogs. So separate instances of viewmodels for each machine is a must here.

Also, Dependancy injection is implemented in MachineDashboardViewModel

```
public MachineDashboardViewModel(IDialogService dialogservice, ILogger logger)
```

So the main question I’m asking is how to dynamically load usercontrols `MachineDashboard` and set appropriate `MachineId` property in its viewmodel?

I created very simplified sample application
[here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgR_6i1-L03lmmrcyLznbIkI_8xq?e=hScBp2)

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward option is to set the `MachineId` on the `MachineDashboardViewModel`s when you create them and put them in the `Machines` property.

Taking a detour from the parent view model to the data template to the user control to to the child view model makes absolutely no sense when the child viewmodels are in a property of the parent view model from the beginning.